# Python - Call a function in a module dynamically

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python and I have a situation where I have a variable representing a function inside of a module and I'm wondering how to call it dynamically. I have `filters.py`:

```
def scale(image, width, height):
    pass
```

And then in another script I have something like:

```
import filters

def process_images(method='scale', options):
    filters[method](**options)
```

... but that doesn't work obviously. If someone could fill me in on the proper way to do this, or let me know if there is a better way to pass around functions as parameters that would be awesome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To avoid the problem, you could pass the function directly, instead of "by name":

```
def process_images(method=filters.scale, options):
    method(**options)
```

If you have a special reason to use a string instead, you can use `getattr` as suggested by SilentGhost.

Answer (score 27):

you need built-in [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org//library/functions.html#getattr):

```
getattr(filters, method)(**options)
```

Comment: this should be the best answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import filters

def process_images(function=filters.scale, options):
    function(**options)
```

This can then be called like, for example:

```
process_images(filters.rotate, **rotate_options)
```

Note that having a default function arg doesn't seem like a good idea -- it's not intuitively obvious why filters.scale is the default out of several possible image-processing operations.